# Can I compile my Silverlight 4 application as a WPF?

Tags: silverlight

Just curious I heard this somewhere... I doubt it is true...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it directly, but you can create a WPF project and [add links to the Silverlight files](http://devblog.ailon.org/devblog/post/2010/01/13/Writing-WPFSilverlight-compatible-code-Part-6-Adding-XAML-files-as-links.aspx).

If you don't use Silverlight-specific code, you'll have a WPF application.